# Infinite loop, won't end with while loop

Tags: java

Ok so I've wrote this program where it will count a certain letters and spaces, what i want it to do was to have user keep entering phrase and it continues to loop until user enter quit to terminate. I'm having trouble seeing where to put the while loop. I know i should nest all loops under the while loop and when i did that, the program goes into an infinite looping.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      String phrase;    // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;         // an individual character in the string
        int countA=0,countE=0,countS=0,countT=0;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Print a program header
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Character Counter");
      System.out.println ();

      // Read in a string and find its length
      System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase or enter (Quit) to quit: ");
        phrase = scan.nextLine();
while(!phrase.equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit"))
{
        length = phrase.length();

            // Initialize counts
            countBlank = 0;

        // a for loop to go through the string character by character

            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) 
        {
            if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') countBlank++;

            switch(ch=phrase.charAt(i)) 
            {
            case 'a':
            case 'A': countA++;
            break;

            case 'e':
            case 'E': countE++;
            break;

            case 's':
            case 'S': countS++;
            break;

            case 't':
            case 'T': countT++;
            break;

        }
     }


      // Print the results
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println ("Number of a: " + countA);
        System.out.println ("Number of e: " + countE);
        System.out.println ("Number of s: " + countS);
        System.out.println ("Number of t: " + countT);
      System.out.println ();

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: first, take "quit", and not "Quit", and you should use ToLower() to be sure that "quItE" = "quit" after tolower.

Comment: do not "initialize" something inside a loop, it will be newly initialized each loop

Answer (score 5):

Within the while loop, you're never reading the next line. You need to add

```
phrase = scan.nextLine();
```

After the 'for' loop, but still within the 'while' loop. Otherwise, phrase will always remain the first thing you read in.

Comment: U mean i should have the while loop nested in the for loop?

Comment: The for loop iterates over each character in the string provided at the command line. You want to continually read new strings from the user, until the user enters "quit." Think about your looping structure. While the user has not entered "quit", you want to loop over each character in their input. Then, you want to read the next string in from the command line, see if it's equal to "quit" and break out of the loop if it is. You should keep the for loop and while loop as they are. You just need to add a call to scan.nextLine(), so that phrase is updated to be the next string the user enters.

Comment: So what u mean is that keep what I have now and add a phrase = scan.nextLine(); inside the for loop? I've tried that before but after i enter a phrase, it wont run through the process

Answer (score 1):

Duplication is really bad, and trying to avoid duplicaiton might be the problem you are encountering (not wanting to put scan.nextLine twice, a very good instinct).  Philippe's answer was otherwise correct I think.

Let me cheat and re-write Philippe's answer in a couple different ways

```
do {
  phrase = scan.nextLine();
  // do stuff
  // ...

} while(!phrase.equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit"));
```

This would eliminate the duplication, but causes "stuff" to be "done" even if the phrase is "Quit", that's not good either--and to add a break would ruin it.

```
while(true) {
    phrase = scan.nextLine();
    if(!phrase.equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit"))
        break;
     // do stuff
 }
```

This works perfectly but the while(true) makes some people REALLY uncomfortable--it's a religion that some people learn at a young age and can't get over, so you may not want to push this one--Some how they have been convinced that this is more likely to result in an "infinite loop" than the other solution, complete garbage since they are functionally correct, but it also hides the loop exit criteria which can be annoying.

Another one that is valid but makes some people uncomfortable:

```
while( (phrase = scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit") ) {
     // do stuff
 }
```

Actually very few people use this in Java--I never even use it and I'm not completely sure it's valid because I don't use it, but I THINK = still returns the value to be operated on.  Anyway, if it's rare enough that I'd have to test it to be sure, it's rare enough to make someone else spend more time looking at it than they should have to, which is bad.

So what's the best solution?  Probably to break it down into method calls:

```
private string phrase;

boolean readPhrase() {
    phrase=scan.nextLine();
    return !phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit");
}

while(readPhrase()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I know it seems like more work, but if you get in the habit of breaking things out into usable pieces like this you'll be much happier in the long run.  You now have more modular, understandable code--and really no cost (Never think of more methods as a cost as long as they are simple, short, understandable methods and you do not repeat logic).

Honestly if you were going to go on and use this for anything real, I'd probably even create a "phrase" class with a .read() method that contained a string variable and a .countCharacter("") method.  that would make your code look like this:

```
while(phrase.read()) {
    System.out.println("Number of a="+phrase.countCharactr("a")); // assume that countCharacter does a toLower()
    System.out.println("Number of a="+phrase.countCharactr("e"));
    ...
}
```

Which suddenly is VERY readable and compact.

Also note that when you reduce code like this, other patterns become easily recognized.  In this case you might even notice that you could factor out the repeated lines above because they only vary by a single character in each case:

```
char[] chars="aest".toCharArray();

while(phrase.read()) 
    for(char c : chars)
        System.out.println("Number of "+c+"="+phrase.countCharactr(c)); // assume that countCharacter does a toLower()
// this is untested and some of the conversions/methods/etc may need tweaking.
```

Your entire "Main" reduced to a few lines and a simple secondary class.  isn't that better?

Sorry about over-analyzing.  Out of work and starting to really miss coding.

Comment: [code]while( (phrase = scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit") ) {
     // do stuff
 }'code'
That answer is the prettiest, and the one I most commonly see in other similar cases like buffered readers.

Comment: @keepitreall89 You'll hear people complain about each solution.  The most readable is almost always not the one people would call "Elegant" or "Pretty".  The most readable is probably the last one (although the name chars was a bad choice, should have used "charsToScan).  It's just about always clearer/more readable to make more methods/classes.  In my experience, readable beats nearly every other trait, but that's just my experience.

Comment: yeah, I know it is more the preference of the programmer since there are several ways to solve each problem, myself I go with the short in lines and width version of the code, then comment to explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should scan a new line at the end of your while loop. The way your loop is constructed now, you keep iterating with the same input.

```
phrase = scan.nextLine();
while(!phrase.equalsIgnoreCase ("Quit")){
  // do stuff
  // ...
  phrase = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Read in a string and find its length
System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase or enter (Quit) to quit: ");

while (true) {
    phrase = scan.nextLine();
    if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) break;

    // Initialize your counter variables here

    length = phrase.length();
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Character Counter

Enter a sentence or phrase or enter (Quit) to quit: What the heck?

Number of blank spaces: 2
Number of a: 1
Number of e: 2
Number of s: 0
Number of t: 2

Hello how are you

Number of blank spaces: 3
Number of a: 2
Number of e: 4
Number of s: 0
Number of t: 2

I have this problem now, the first one it counted correctly, but after i entered the second phrase, the result is added to the first. Can see u the error?

Comment: All of your count variables maintain their old value. You need to reset them all to = 0 at the start of your while loop.

Comment: Ok so i shouldn't set them to zero at the beginning, that makes sense, thanks so much.